# How to decide where the SQLite file is stored in QML LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, mobile, qml

I have this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

property var db // the database of this application
property string dbIdentifier: '/Users/cedo/desktop/test/DatabaseApplicationDB.db'
property string dbVersion: '1.0'
property string dbDescription: 'DatabaseApplicationDB'
property int dbEstimatedSize: 1000000

Component.onCompleted: {
    db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(dbIdentifier, dbVersion, dbDescription, dbEstimatedSize);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var sql = "create table if not exists mytable(id integer)";
        tx.executeSql(sql);
    });

}
}
```

The dbIdentifier works when the database is created but when I go to search for the db file in the desktop the file is not there. Where is it? Or how to decide where to put it?

Answer (score 2):

According to **openDatabaseSync()** method [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#opendatabasesync), the function prototype is:

```
object openDatabaseSync(string name, string version, string description, int estimated_size, jsobject callback(db))
```

> **name** is the database name
>
> **version** is the database version
>
> **description** is the database display name
>
> **estimated_size** is the database's estimated size, in bytes
>
> **callback** is an optional parameter, which is invoked if the database has not yet been created.

So there is no file name parameter. Again, according to [documentations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#detailed-description):

> These databases are user-specific and QML-specific, but accessible to all QML applications. **They are stored in the Databases subdirectory of QQmlEngine::offlineStoragePath(), currently as SQLite databases.**

To be able to put your database files into some custom directory, you should use **setOfflineStoragePath(const QString &dir)** function of your **QQmlEngine** or **QQmlApplicationEngine** instance.

To see where your database files are currently in, use this C++ code:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
qDebug() << engine.offlineStoragePath();
```

More info [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#offlineStoragePath-prop) and [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/3283/loading-sqlite-database-within-the-project-directory)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, it is `.local/share/*project_name*/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases`